# How to control the content of a .gml output of a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, export

Say there's a `.gml` file with a graph:

```
Export["g.gml", Graph[{UndirectedEdge[0, 1], UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 0]}], "Graphlet"]
```

It looks like so:

```
Creator "the Wolfram Language for Students - Personal Use Only : www.wolfram.com"
graph [
    directed 0
    node [ 
        id 0
        graphics [
            fill "#828FA3"
            outline "#000000"
            x -0.866025
            y -0.5
        ]
    ]
    node [ 
        id 1
        graphics [
            fill "#828FA3"
            outline "#000000"
            x 0.866025
            y -0.5
        ]
    ]
    node [ 
        id 2
        graphics [
            fill "#828FA3"
            outline "#000000"
            x 0
            y 1.
        ]
    ]
    edge [ 
        source 0
        target 1
        graphics [
            fill "#828FA3"
        ]
    ]
    edge [ 
        source 1
        target 2
        graphics [
            fill "#828FA3"
        ]
    ]
    edge [ 
        source 2
        target 0
        graphics [
            fill "#828FA3"
        ]
    ]
]
```

How to `Export` a `Graph` so that there are no `graphics [ ]` in the output file? I.e., it looks like so:

```
Creator "the Wolfram Language for Students - Personal Use Only : www.wolfram.com"
graph [
    directed 0
    node [ 
        id 0
    ]
    node [ 
        id 1
    ]
    node [ 
        id 2
    ]
    edge [ 
        source 0
        target 1
    ]
    edge [ 
        source 1
        target 2
    ]
    edge [ 
        source 2
        target 0
    ]
]
```

Comment: Why do you need GML? Would another format work? (I can imagine many reasons why one would want GML. I am asking in the hope that we could deal with the issue that forced you to use GML in the first place.)

Comment: @Szabolcs I am using an external C [programme](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/communities/) for clustering that takes as an input gml. And it fails on MMA generated files, so I want to get rid of the graphics in the output (i.e., this is the only difference between MMA files and examples of the authors, like Les Miserables network or karate club, so I strongly suspect it's the culprit). And I don't want to fiddle with C (code written by some other researchers and made available online; and I'm no C wizard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post-process the output. It's a hack, but it's easy and practical.

```
fixGML[str_] := 
 StringDelete[str, Whitespace ~~ "graphics [" ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ "]"]
```

```
fixGML@ExportString[
  Graph[{UndirectedEdge[0, 1], UndirectedEdge[1, 2], 
    UndirectedEdge[2, 0]}], "Graphlet"]
```

```
"Creator \"the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com\"
graph [
    directed 0
    node [ 
        id 0
    ]
    node [ 
        id 1
    ]
    node [ 
        id 2
    ]
    edge [ 
        source 0
        target 1
    ]
    edge [ 
        source 1
        target 2
    ]
    edge [ 
        source 2
        target 0
    ]
]
"
```

I have no reason to believe that the output that Mathematica produces here is invalid. More likely, the software you are using only has limited support for reading it. Unfortunately, I can no longer find the original GML spec to check.